# Issue with recursive Function and returning 0

Tags: c, recursion

I want to write a function that increases each individual digit of an int by 1, if a digit is 9 it remains the same. It works for every value other than 0 (want to output 1) but if i were to return 1 when n == 0 every other value is then thrown off.

```c
int shift_digits(int n){
    if(n == 0){
        return 0;
    }else{
        int lastDigit = n % 10;
        if(lastDigit == 9){
            return 10 * shift_digits(n/10) + lastDigit;
        }else{
            return 10 * shift_digits(n/10) + lastDigit + 1;
        }
    }
}
```

(With return 0 when n == 0):

```
Input- 1234
Output- 2345

Input- 8980
Output- 9991
```

(With return 1 when n == 0):

```
Input- 0
Output- 1

Input- 4278
Output- 15389
```

Comment: Curious, what result do you expect when `n < 0` or when the result is more than `INT_MAX`?

Comment: Note: Both [`inc_digits(x)`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77867110/2410359) and [`shift_digits(x)`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77866666/2410359) give the same result for all `x >= 0`.

Answer (score 3):

Passing a zero from the start (which should result in 1) is different from passing a zero from a recursive call (which should result in 0).

Don't recurse if `(n/10) == 0` and the whole thing unbreaks.

```
int shift_digits(int n) {
    int lastDigit = n % 10;
    int prefix = 0;
    if (n/10) { prefix = shift_digits(n/10); }
    if (lastDigit != 9) { lastDigit++; }
    return 10 * prefix + lastDigit;
}
```

Comment: For those who like hard to read 1-liners: `int shift_digits_alt(int n) { return 10 * ((n/10) ? shift_digits_alt(n/10) : 0) + (n % 10 == 9 ? 9 : n % 10 + 1); }`.
`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it is much clearer, but you should be able to rewrite the whole thing as:

```c
int inc_digits (int n, bool first)
{
  if(n == 0)
  {
    return first;
  }

  int last_digit = n%10;
  return 10 * inc_digits(n/10,0) + last_digit + (last_digit!=9);
}
#define inc_digits(n) inc_digits(n,1)
```

With the little trick of `last_digit!=9` being a boolean expression evaluating to 1 in case the digit isn't 9, otherwise 0.

It handles the situation of n==0 during the first call by a second parameter. The evil macro at the end is a hack to preserve the 1 parameter API of the function while still handling that `n==0` special case. (Using a `static` member to solve that special case is discouraged.)

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int inc_digits (int n, bool first)
{
  if(n == 0)
  {
    return first;
  }

  int last_digit = n%10;
  return 10 * inc_digits(n/10,0) + last_digit + (last_digit!=9);
}
#define inc_digits(n) inc_digits(n,1)

int main(void) 
{
  int test_cases[] = {5555, 9999, 123456789, 0};

  for(size_t i=0; i<sizeof test_cases/sizeof *test_cases; i++)
  {
    printf("%d\n", inc_digits(test_cases[i]));
  }
}
```

Output:

```
6666
9999
234567899
1
```

Notably this is a horribly inefficient algorithm containing recursion, division and multiple branches. There's likely other tricks to do this way more efficiently. At least the compiler (latest gcc) did manage to tail call optimize, so it is only mildly horrible, at least as far as recursion goes.

Comment: "Notably this is a horribly inefficient algorithm "  --> Are you suggesting a better O() algorithm or are the _(mildly) horribly inefficient_ just linear concerns?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Getting rid of the recursion is a fine start. "Big O" is pretty irrelevant since it knows nothing of things like the inefficiency of integer division on certain ISA.